# Using dust.js templates with backbone.marionette and require.js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, dust.js

I am building a large scale application using backbone and marionette. Instead of using underscore templating engine, I am planning to use dust.js.

I have found [marionette-dust](https://github.com/simonblee/marionette-dust) plugin which could do the job but currently I am at a loss in understanding how to use it with require.js. Also, it there a better way of implementing dust besides using this plugin?

Feedback appreciated.

Following is the code in sample application

### testView.js

```
  define(["app", "templates/test.dust"], function(app, testTpl){
    app.module("test.view", function(view, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

      view.list = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: testTpl,
      });
    });

    return app.test.view;
  });
```

### test.dust

```
(function() {
  dust.register("demo", body_0);

  function body_0(chk, ctx) {
    return chk.write("This is Dust.js Test");
  }
  return body_0;
})();
```

### main.js

```
    requirejs.config({
      baseUrl: "assets/js",
      paths: {
        backbone: "vendor/backbone-min",
        jquery: "vendor/jquery-min",
        marionette: "vendor/backbone.marionette-min",
        tpl: "vendor/tpl",
        underscore: "vendor/underscore-min",
        dust: "vendor/dust",
        dustHelpers: 'vendor/dust-helpers',    
        dustMarionette: "vendor/backbone.marionette.dust",
        templates: 'templates/compiled',    
      },

      shim: {
        jquery: {
          exports: 'jquery'
        },

        underscore: {
          exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
          deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
          exports: "Backbone"
        },
        marionette: {
          deps: ["backbone"],
          exports: "Marionette"
        },

        dust: {
            exports: 'dust'
        },
        dustHelpers: ['dust'],
        templates: ['dust', 'dustMarionette']
      }
    });

    require(["app"], function(app){
      app.start();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of that plugin. Basically you need to define the three dependencies 
'backbone', 'dust' and 'marionette' in your Requirejs config file and then define
the AMD version of this module as a dependency after marionette during the initial application setup.

The plugin is written under the assumption that you have compiled all of your dust templates and they are in the dust cache (you should find details on how to do that in the dust documentation). You may see why if you have a look at the plugin source code. Inside of each your views simply set the `template` property to the name of the template in the dust cache that you want to use.

The plugin overrides the `render` function in the `Marionette.Renderer` object that is used by all views. So basically under the hood, Marionette is calling the `render` function of this plugin which renders the templates with Dust and then returns the HTML. Marionette's documentation [here](http://marionettejs.com/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-153) mentions this is the best way to provide custom rendering.

I've tried to outline all of this in the Readme file for the plugin but if you think it can be improved (which I don't doubt it can) then please let me know which areas are unclear.

I've written a Yeoman generator called [generator-maryo](https://github.com/simonblee/generator-maryo) to provide scaffolding for a marionette and dust web application. There are still a few todos in there but it provides you with a good foundation on how to use the marionette-dust plugin with marionette. If I can be more explicit in any area then let me know.

**EDIT AFTER CODE ADDED TO QUESTION**

The marionette-dust plugin is access by template name, not by the compiled template function. So essentially you need to run the compiled template function (which it should do by itself as it's an anonymous function), then it will be placed in the dust cache under the name "demo". So your item view should look like:

```
define(["app", "templates/test.dust"], function(app, testTpl){
    app.module("test.view", function(view, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

        view.list = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: "demo",
        });
    });

    return app.test.view;
});
```

Note that all I did was set the `template` property to "demo". Also, is this all of the code for the demo app? You need to actually show the view using a region or you can just call the `render` function on the view manually. To get something working quickly, you can do something like this:

```
myView = new app.test.view;
$('body').append(myView.render().$el);
```

Also, why are you wrapping the view in a module block? As you're already using RequireJS, Marionette's module system is not really necessary. I am in the process of writing a demo app for Marionette using generator-maryo which will probably explain a lot. Keep an eye out for it in the github repo.

Comment: Thank you Simon for the lighting reply. I really appreciate your help. I did install generator-maryo and created a sample scaffolding. I sill have a newbie question creating the view file. I am still not able to render the following template and not sure what i am doing wrong. attached is the view and config file for your perusal.

Comment: I've added to my answer. Also, check out this gist https://gist.github.com/simonblee/6227441. It's not useing RequireJS but may help.

Comment: I feel really stupid to re comment ... but I did make the suggested changes to the code and am now I am getting "Error: Script error for: templates/test.dust" error. Not sure what I could be doing wrong. Appreciate the big help. For some reason the code is not able to translate compiled dust code. Here is the gist of the sample app ... https://gist.github.com/unagi2020/9321251

Comment: I had enclosed most of the code in modules to keep code modular and easy to debug. Does enclosing code in Marionette's module system add overhead ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the error you're getting. I import my dust templates in a different way to you. Basically all of my templates are compiled into a single javascript file called templates.js. I then import that file during my initial application setup. Then all of the templates are available in the dust cache when the application starts. As far as I can tell, your method should still work as it's almost the same, just that you're importing them only when you use them. I don't have time to set up your app at the moment so I suggest you try to debug your code and I'll try to get back to you.

Comment: As for using Marionette's modules, it's not so much that it adds overhead, just that it's not necessary. When you write each of your objects as amd modules, they are already modules by definition. Essentially, you're creating a module within a module. Also, I think of Marionette's modules as larger entities than you appear to be using them as. For instance, a "chat" module rather than each object within a chat module being modules themselves, if you catch my meaning. https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/AMD-Modules-vs-Marionette's-Modules#wiki-which-is-right-for-you

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the non-usage of modules in views. It makes perfect sense. I had been creating separate application for larger modules and modules for sub-modules. I will rearrange the application based on this discussion. Regarding the error on rendering dust template ... It is a require error and not backbone error. I have found translation [plugin](https://github.com/webpro/requirejs-dust) which got rid of the error but is not render anything on the page. Scratching my head on rendering part. Again appreciate you taking time to diligently reply to my queries. Have a good day.

Comment: The require error probably has to do with the file extension of your dust file. In fact, your dust template is a compiled javascript function, so it's not really in 'dust' template format anymore. So I'd just call it 'templates/test.js'. Then in Require you simply use 'templates/test' which should execute as a script. To check if it's added to the Dust cache, run `dust.cache` in your browser console. You should see an object with a 'demo' (name of your template) property. If you don't then require is not executing your compiled template, which I suspect is what's happening.